# Add a product tag to product name in Woocommerce archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to add product tag below product name on Woocommerce. I found a similar code here and tried to customize it but i can't get it work.

```
/**
 * Add product's brand name to product's name.
 */
add_filter( 'the_title', 'mycode_add_brand_to_product_title', 10, 2 );
function mycode_add_brand_to_product_title( $title, $id ) {
  $type = get_post_type( $id ); 
  if ( $type != 'product' ) { return $title; }
  $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' );
  $brand = array_shift( $terms );
  if ( !empty( $brand ) ) {
    $title = $brand . ' ' . $title;
  }
  return $title;
}
```

Could someone please help?

Here's a preview what i want to achieve:

[image: Add tag below name - Woocommerce]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:** Try the following:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'mycode_add_brand_to_product_title', 10, 2 );
function mycode_add_brand_to_product_title( $title, $post_id ) {

    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) != 'product' && ! is_archive() )
        return $title;

    if ( ! ( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ) )
        return $title;

    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'product_tag' );
    $term = reset( $terms );

    if ( !empty( $term->name ) )
        $title .= '<br><small>' . strtoupper( $term->name ) . '</small>';

    return $title;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works. 
 It should work for you too.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing?
How to display this only on Archive pages? Because now it shows it everywhere!